# How to detect in advance if a browser will download a file instead of viewing it?

Tags: browser, download

Sometimes when you view a file on a page on its own, the browser has some default way of viewing it, like to place it in an image or video tag, or invoke some plugin.  Other times, it just downloads the file.

Sometimes this is because of headers set by the server, but lets ignore that for now.  For some file types, it doesn't matter what headers were set -- the browser will try to download them regardless.

Some of the types that the browser will view are listed in navigator.mimeTypes.  However, this is not authoritative.  The iPad can view Microsoft Office files but it does not report this.

Is there any simple way to figure out what the browser is going to do with a file before it does it?